# How to survive a fall from a skyscraper by having super powers to turn yourself into mushrooms?

Tags: biology, physics, super-powers, health, microorganisms

Given:

0. The character falls from a skyscraper, 200-300 meters high
1. The character has a super-ability to transform their muscles and tissues into yeast, mycelium, fungi, slime molds, spores, and similar model organisms.
   2.The force does not apply to the skeleton.
2. Brain transformation, suicide.
3. The brain weighs up to 2kg, the skeleton up to 14kg.
4. Presumably before hitting the ground 6-9 seconds.
5. The transformation is instantaneous,
6. Turning a one-way road.
7. You can synthesize any drugs from mushrooms, but now there is no time for this.
8. Telekinetic control over created organisms. The maximum speed of movement on the ground from 1 mm in 1 second to 6 mm

Question:

1. How to survive?
2. Save at least the brain.

ps. sry, my eng is bad

Comment: Does #6 mean that the transformation cannot be reversed?

Comment: is true.  you can transform from one mushroom to another, but you can't transform back into a human body.

Comment: 1.2 means the ability doesn't apply to the skeleton or the force of the impact? Also do we need nornal blood circulation and such for the brain still?

Comment: From the large amount of comments below: wouldn't it be better to rephrase it that all the brain needs to do is survive the fall. No blood or oxygen needed?

Comment: @Trioxidane needs blood & oxygen, to save the brain. Ability doesn't apply to the skeleton. The body can die, but the brain must alive and live a few weeks in consciousness. Feeding with mushroom... In perfect plan

Comment: [The beginning of wisdom](https://youtu.be/RLpsIuhTb8k) So, the question is, what happens if a substantial amount of mushroom is removed from contact with the superhero?

Comment: If they can't transform back to human afterwards, then I would say they don't survive the transformation into mushrooms, let alone the fall from a skyscraper.

Comment: @g0ldenlights If I cant transform back into a human, whats the point? I'd *rather* die.

Comment: @JBH  I think I didn't understand the question
but... let's say you can switch to feeding the brain with oxygen and glucose through mushrooms. 
then if the hero sends the mushrooms for a walk, too far from himself, it will lead to oxygen starvation, sepsis, and death.

Comment: @Len again, I don't seem to understand the question... being human means being high on neurotransmitters. Mushrooms can synthesize substances that stimulate the production of neurotransmitters in the brain. You can replace sex with serotonin, social interactions with oxytocin, work with dopamine, winning with norepinephrine. Everything you do, you do for a dose of neurotransmitters. Here, only the method of high will change. And death is something completely different. The absolute end. Unless you're a lunatic who believes in the afterlife.

Comment: @g0ldenlights Think of it this way: if your superhero converts everything but the critical bits (like the brain) to mushrooms, what will happen on impact will be most of the mushroom exploding off into the distance - not unlike the watermelon. That means your superhero will experience a critical reduction in mass and loss of contact with that mass. Without the ability to bring that mass back, there will be problems (as you indicated). Therefore, one of the most pressing issues for you to consider is that happens when mass is lost due to compressive destabilization upon impact (poof!)?

Comment: Also, butting into your conversation with @Len - "everything you do, you do for a dose of neurotransmitters" is technically true, but so simplistic that it begs the question how well you understand the purpose of neurotransmitters. Len's question didn't actually have anything to do with that aspect of mushrooms (and although I'm not a pharmacologist by any stretch of the imagination... I suspect you're giving fungi a bit more credit than they deserve). We're all questioning the *mechanics* of the problem. Not the chemistry, about which there seems to be little relevance to your Q.

Comment: @JBH my goal was to point out that living in an inhuman form, in the form of brain+mushrooms, is better than death. Yes, my knowledge of neurotransmitters is superficial.

Comment: @g0ldenlights Actually, that helps considerably. Not understanding your goals and expectations led to I (and probably others) making assumptions. I think there could be a lot of fun to be had helping you flesh out your world and the rules governing your superheros. If it makes sense, my suggestion is to ask questions in smaller chunks, meaning that you help us understand specifically what you're trying to achieve with your question. At least a few of us were confused by why the chemistry mattered here. I'm hoping to see more questions about your world!

Comment: @JBH your words warm my corpus amygdaloideum))

Answer (score 7):

## You're dead anyway

I was going to calculate  the parachute area required for base jumping with that mass, but then it came to me that mycelium is not a proper fabric for this. So your best bet would be to mushify all soft tissue for cushion, but then you will have no circulation and as such will be brain dead for want of oxygen.

I think the death by impact is quicker and thus preferred, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: minimum viable modification to the requirements: the brain can survive (but not operate) for long enough without oxygen (already satisfied if the fungi work fast enough); the pile of myceliums has enough intelligence to manufacture a rudimentary heart and lungs for the brain (or rather: just about anything that will get oxygen to the brain... or even, let's modify the brain so that it can use atmospheric oxygen when unsheathed).

Comment: So your best bet would be to mushify all soft tissue for cushion, but then you will have no circulation and as such will be brain dead for want of oxygen.______________________________________________________________________ Wait but you can not touch the blood vessels, heart and lungs. So that they continue to supply the brain with oxygen and glucose.

Comment: or even, let's modify the brain so that it can use atmospheric oxygen when unsheathed___________________________________________________________ weird shit, and how do I do it?)))

Comment: @g0ldenlights you will have to handwave a lot more than that. Blood vessels have their pressure regulated in part by musculature. Remove all those tissues around vessels and they might pop. As for the brain taking oxygen directly from the atmosphere, that means exposing the brain to the atmosphere - so instead of dying in a moment from impact, you die in hours from sepsis. The brain is a very sensitive organ, [our clade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craniate) evolved a cranium for good reason.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I think the human brain can already survive but not operate for a few minutes without oxygen. Usually such survival comes with damage from anoxia, but hey, you can't make an omelet without sacrificing some faculties.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw, what if you replace the vessels with fungi like Mycetozoa? Will this be enough to feed the brain with blood and oxygen? Leave the lungs, heart, and brain connected by a fungal circulatory system?

Comment: @g0ldenlights no.

Comment: I agree you are dead no matter what, you can't change the brain or skull which means you need to drastically reduce the impact energy, but you will need basically all the rest of the body mass just to keep the brain alive with a mycelium based system. the brain is a thirty beast, it consumes a tremendous amount of oxygen and calories.

Comment: what if you try to make the skin of the whole body, as well as the muscles of the arms and legs - a structure that will decompose into a parachute and you will hang on the tendons(arms and legs) and a mushroom parachute. 
Stop the bleeding by creating mushroom plugs.
from the article about vegan leather, there is chitin in mushrooms. Chitin, isn't it durable? A fungal structure with a high content of chitin?

Comment: @g0ldenlights this all introduces more problems than it solves. Also chitin is hard, parachutes are soft. You know what else is made of chitin? Arthropod exoskeletons. You are trying to make a parachute out of ant carapace.

Answer (score 2):

### Goodbye Limbs, Hello Water

... though they may be back if the brain can handwave drug-production and has a good diet.

You'll have to play with your parameters, but mushrooms be converted to a leather-like substance under the right circumstances. This is produced today and marketed as "vegan leather". Forming this into a glider, you might be able to make it to a water-body or at least lengthen your flight.

Using the mass of limbs for this and dropping some of the bones you can't convert, you could potentially splash down relatively softly, perhaps enough for the major organs to survive. Your glider/parachute is now a flotation device until your reach shore.

After that, survival is in the hands of rescuers, local wildlife eating the wreck, and the ability to feed. Photosynthesis won't be enough to power the brain, but eating wildlife might be.

Then, if you survive...

---

### Handwaved Biomanipulation

With the right drugs (and some handwaving to let the mushrooms know what to produce and where), it is possible to convert some stem cells into "embryonic" stem cells which can differentiate into arbitrary tissues. These cells can build an entire body naturally, so regrowing the lost limbs given the right nutrition can be handwaved by mushroom-dosed biochemistry - salamanders are able to regenerate lost limbs perfectly, which gives you a precedent.

Hunting pigeons with mushroom-made poisons or LSD could give this character enough to eat, in an urban setting without rescue. Smaller creatures could be more of a problem, and unfriendly humans would probably be.

Comment: hmm mushroom skin is an invention created by compressing and treating with acids. Good idea but hmm))